# What is the correct syntax for this composite function involving absolute values and root signs?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, radicals, absolute-value

For composite function: $$f(g(x))$$

where $$f(x)=-5-|x|$$

and $$g(x)=\sqrt x$$

what is the correct expansion of $$f(g(x)) ?$$

Is it: $$-5-\sqrt  \lvert x \rvert$$

Or should it be written: $$-5-\lvert \sqrt x\rvert ?$$

In the first case, I believe the domain to be $x \in \mathbb{R}$, since the absolute value function renders all $x \geq 0$, so it is never the case that the radical is negative.  However the second case implies that the domain is restricted to $x \geq 0$

The text I am working out of gives the answer to the question of the domain as $x \geq 0$.  This suggests to me that the authors rendered $f(g(x))$ as $-5-\lvert \sqrt x\rvert $

However a graphing calculator I am using (in which I have defined the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as above) converts $f(g(x))$ to: $$-(\sqrt  \lvert x \rvert)-5$$ and thus the domain is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that it’s graph is a “wave crest” with peak -5 at $x=0$.  This is again contrary to the text which says that the graph is the reflection of the $\sqrt x$ “reflected in the y” axis.

In all probability, the authors are right and I’m still getting a handle on how to use and define functions in the graphing calculator (NCalc Fx).

Screenshots for clarity.

[image: function definitions and complex arrangement]

[image: wavecrest graph of f of g of x]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just work it out step by step. We have that

$$f(g(x)) = - 5 - |g(x)| = - 5 - |\sqrt x|$$

The graphing calculator is wrong. For what it's worth, a different graphing calculator, [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3jjrlvfjjn), agrees with me.

> However the second case implies that the domain is restricted to $x \gt 0$

Actually the domain includes $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks @PrincessEev I have corrected my oversight and will contact the calculators developer.  Could be the case that I just need to add something to the syntax when using it to get the right result.